# servidor udp não recebe a mensagem do cliente udp linux

Tags: c

Bom,eu estava programando um sistema simples de troca de mensagens,quando testei no mesmo computador,funcionou corretamente sem problema algum,porém quando testei em dois computadores diferentes,o servidor não recebeu a mensagem do cliente que eu criei,alguém poderia me ajudar?

codigo do cliente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFFTAM 1024  //Tamanho maximo do buffer
#define PORTA 8888   //A porta na qual sera enviado os dados

void terminar(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

void IniciarCliente()
{
    struct sockaddr_in servidorsock;/*definindo as variaveis*/
    int s, slen=sizeof(servidorsock);
    char buf[BUFFTAM];
    char mensagem[BUFFTAM];

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1){
        terminar("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &servidorsock, 0, sizeof(servidorsock));
    servidorsock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servidorsock.sin_port = htons(PORTA);

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &servidorsock.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(strcmp(buf,"fim\n")!=0){
        printf("Digite uma mensagem : ");
        fgets(mensagem,BUFFTAM,stdin);

        //Envia a mensagem
        if (sendto(s, mensagem, strlen(mensagem) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &servidorsock, slen)==-1){
            terminar("sendto()");
        }

        //recebe uma mensagem de volta e printa ela na tela
        //limpa o buffer de dados
        memset(buf,'\0', BUFFTAM);
        printf("pacote enviado com sucesso!");
        //tenta receber dados do servidor
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFFTAM, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servidorsock, (socklen_t *)&slen) == -1){
            terminar("recvfrom()");
        }
        printf("pacote recebido com sucesso!");
        //printa os dados recebidos
        printf("%s\n",buf);
    }

    close(s);
}

int main()
{
    IniciarCliente();
    return 0;
}
```

codigo do servidor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define BUFFTAM 1024
#define PORTA 8888

void terminar(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

void IniciarServer(){
    struct sockaddr_in servidorsock, cliente;
    int s, slen = sizeof(cliente);

    char buf[BUFFTAM];

    //cria um scoket udp
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1){
        terminar("socket");
    }

    // zera a estrutura
    memset((char *) &servidorsock, 0, sizeof(servidorsock));

    servidorsock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servidorsock.sin_port = htons(PORTA);
    servidorsock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //faz o bind do socket com a porta
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&servidorsock, sizeof(servidorsock) ) == -1){
        terminar("bind");
    }

    //espera por dados
    while(strcmp(buf,"fim\n")!=0){
        printf("Esperando por dados\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        memset(buf,'\0',BUFFTAM);

        //tenta receber algum dado do cliente
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFFTAM, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliente, (socklen_t*)&slen) == -1){
            terminar("recvfrom()");
        }

        //imprime os dados recebidos
        printf("Origem do cliente %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(cliente.sin_addr), ntohs(cliente.sin_port));
        printf("mensagem: %s\n" , buf);

        printf("Digite a mensagem que deseja enviar ao cliente : ");
        fgets(buf,BUFFTAM,stdin);

        //retorna o cliente com a mensagem
        if (sendto(s, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cliente, slen) == -1){
            terminar("sendto()");
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    IniciarServer();
    return 0;
}
```

eu não sei exatamente oque é,eu ja revisei esse codigo de cima a baixo,mais ainda não consiguir achar oque tem de errado nele,se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeceria

Comment: É em uma rede local?

Comment: sim,e em uma rede local,ja fiz de tudo,tentei redirecionar a porta no meu ip,ja tentei mudar as configurações do mac do meu roteador e nada

Comment: como está conectando as máquinas?

Comment: pela minha rede

Comment: Digo vc tem 2 pcs que se conectam através de cabo? O cabo é o cabo correto?

Comment: não,os dois se conectam via wireless(rede sem fio)

Comment: certo tho pensar aqui

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61396/discussion-between-magichat-and-rez).

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema,pra quem estiver com o mesmo problema que eu,vai a solução:

Se você estiver ultilizando duas máquinas diferentes para se conectar,você precisará ir nas configurações do seu roteador e tentar alterar o IP dinâmico da sua máquina gerado pelo roteador e torná-lo um IP estático na sua rede,a partir disso você poderá usar esta máquina como um servidor,e outra máquina qualquer como cliente,mas lembre-se de definir o IP estático que você criou no servidor no código do cliente para seja possível realizar a conexão.

> **Dica:** tente procurar algum programa que faça isso(alterar o IP dinâmico de uma máquina para um IP estático),pois tornar o ip da sua máquina como estático pelo roteador é uma tarefa bem trabalhosa

Se você estiver ultilizando uma máquina virtual(VM ou virtual machine),que foi o meu caso,o processo se torna mais simples,ao selecionar a sua VM você só precisará configurar a sua rede nat em **Arquivo**->**preferências**->**Rede**,e adicionar o ip do cliente e o ip do servidor(que seria a VM) e digitar a porta na qual você ultilizaria,dae você entraria em **configurações** e configuraria a opção host-only na sua VM,e poderia ultilizar ela como um servidor,neste link explica com mais detalhes tudo que você precisa saber para configurar a sua VM:
https://terminaldeinformacao.com/2013/10/29/criando-conexao-host-only-no-virtualbox/
,lembrando novamente que você precisará definir o IP estático do seu servidor no código do cliente para que seja possível realizar a conexão